# Curve very sharp after converting from mesh

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have converted an edge loop to a curve. The edge loop itself was fairly low poly. I want the curve to look smooth so I tried to increase the resolution of it but it looks exactly the same.

[image]

Is there a way I can get the curve to be a smooth interpolation of the edge loop?

**[blende file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28013)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the converted curve is a *Poly* spline.

To convert it to a smoothly interpolated curve:

1. Convert it to a Bezier or NURBS spline in *3D view > Tool shelf > Curve Tools > Set Spline Type*:

   [image]
2. Then convert all the Control Vertices to *Auto* (or something besides *vector*) by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>*> Select all* <kbd>V</kbd>*> Automatic*.

Now you can adjust the *Resolution* as desired to adjust the "smoothness":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After converting the mesh to a curve, go into edit mode, then in the Modeling section of the Tools tab, click on Smooth several times.

[image]